# Installing enum34 on Python 3.x breaks pip for Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I used PythonAnywhere to host some Python scripts that required the `fbchat` module. I installed the module on Python 3.6 (with user scheme) without using virtualenv, and the module installed `enum34` as a dependency.

I know `enum34` is incompatible with Python versions greater than 3.4. However I can't uninstall it now either because calling pip3.x gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.6", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

and the command `$ python3.6 -m pip` gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import locale
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

These are the exact steps to reproduce, and the only commands used to get here:

```
$ pip3.6 install --user fbchat
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just delete the package from your `site-packages` folder manually.

Locate it first:

```
python3.6 -c 'import enum; print(enum.__file__)'
```

then delete the whole `enum` directory that file lives in, it'll be in a `site-packages` directory. Delete the `enum34-<version>.dist-info` file next to it too.

Because you used `--user`, the package was installed in your user-site directory. You can get the location with the `site` module too:

```
python3.6 -m site --user-site
```

so you can remove the offending package with:

```
rm -rf `python3.6 -m site --user-site`/enum 
rm `python3.6 -m site --user-site`/enum-*.dist-info
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed my problem. I will be able to accept this answer in 3 minutes.